# acessing tables with wpdb in a wordpress MU

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to use wpdb class to get the post id from the top-level site in a WP-MU environment from one of the sub-sites using a meta value from the sub site.
The following code pulls from the wp_2_postmeta table.

```
$result = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT post_id FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_value LIKE '%".$lname."%'");
```

BUT I want to pull from the wp_postmeta table in the same database. i tried with explicit prefix: $wpdb->wp_postmeta

That doesnt work.

How can you specify the wp_postmeta table explictly using wpdb with WP MU?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to hardcoded ?

You can try to enter the wp_postmeta directly into the query.

I know that is not so good solution, but if you create that code for your personal usage then you can try it ;)